# dropdown menu not working inside perspective library of js when it is loaded inside gridster library

Tags: javascript, jquery, perspective, gridster

I am loading perspective library of js inside gridster library,I have given static data inside the perspective library.
var gridster = $(".gridster-container ul").gridster().data('gridster');

this code written for gridster which works fine but theme button dont work after clicking on it. is there any way to make click event workking. or make changes in above code.

I am trying to make changes using jquery, I cant find specific element inside css as it shows it has shadow root. pointed out buttons not working.